# What sort of starting strategy should I take as Zerg with the aim of going Air in mid game?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

I've almost reached Diamond league, now I need to know how I can get a win without depending on the idiot magnet strategy!!

If there is a need for an even faster expansion to Vespene or to both Vespene and Minerals.

Comment: Do **not** use derogatory terms on Arqade like "retard". [Please take a minute to review our Be Nice policy.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: @Wipqozn While not a nice term, the ["retard magnet"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cl_6q557AkY) is kind-of well known. I don't disagree with your comment, I'm just providing some context.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Thanks for the context. It's still not acceptable, though.

Comment: @Tetris - you should avoid questions like 'what is the *best*' when it comes to strategy, because the 'best' strategy will change depending on your opponent, the map, and a whole host of other factors. I've made a change to the question title to reflect this, please review and let me know if it is acceptable :). It would also help if you can provide any more detail. Can you expand on your current approach? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: The answer is simply: get to the mid game. So play something safe (not necessarily defensive, but not all in) and economical (relatively fast expands). Once you get to the mid game, you can do whatever you want. Remember though that air is weak in a head on fight, so use your air to scout, if they look like they're gearing up to attack/all in, you need to be prepared, it's great having a few mutas to kill all their workers, but it's pretty pointless if their army just walks straight into your base and destroys everything.

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is no simple answer to this question. It is not about build orders or when you get the Vespene gas. Of course gas is important for zerg air, however, you can't talk about a timed zerg army as you can do it with terran or protoss. Zerg air army is so fregile and lack of DPS, therefore you can only make it by transitioning.

We should discuss this strategy based on match-ups.
Let's go with Blizzard race order:

First Terran, ZvT, Terran's basic army unit can shoot air, marines. And it can beat almost anything in the air of Zerg. Against Terran it is almost impossible to win just with air in mid game. You should always have something in the ground. And, you can't just win with Muttas against Terran since it has so many options to counter them. So, you can only aim transitioning late game air with Brood Lords. Brood Lords are so late it is impossible to use them in the mid-game. Let's assume we are talking about mid-late game, in order to switch a heavy air army with mutta, corruptor, brood lord, viper you need a lot of gas, a lot! Therefore, you need to defend well against Terran attacks until like 10min. And then transition into a complete air army slowly. You shouldn't rush it.

Second matchup is with Zerg, ZvZ. It is pretty commmon to see mutta versus mutta in ZvZ. Since zerg doesn't have a lot option to attack air as other races, you can easily switch into mid game Mutta and corruptor army. You can even rush it if you prevent your opponent from seeing it. If you are rushing into Mutta, you should know that you are really weak against all-ins. Therefore, it is good to have baneling nest and static defenses in front door of your natural. If you want to go to fast mutta or slow mutta doesn't matter, you shouldn't get your drones from gas, they should always harvest one gas by the time you have spawning pool and as soon as you start morphing your Hatchery to Lair, you have to start collecting gas from other gas. There is no certain build order for that but if you think you are safe you can take all 4 of the gases.

And the final race Protoss. Protoss have strong counters to mutta, however, if protoss cannot figure out that you are going mutta they can suffer a lot. If you are playing a pretty standard game against protoss, you can transition from ling+hydra to ling+mutta and then if your opponent goes phoenix you can counter with corruptors. You can watch this day9 analysis for scarlett's strategy against protoss

However, keep in mind that if your opponent is dedicated to air I prefer going queen + hydra + infestor as quick reaction, It is too difficult to win against protoss air with zerg air.

To sum up, don't rush it. Make sure you are safe. Always transition from sth depending on the race.